# Tuning SparkR using alternate configs in sparkR.session()

Tags: r, performance, apache-spark, cluster-computing, sparkr

This seems pretty straightforward. I have a cluster, I can choose maximum numbers of executors, cores per executor, RAM per executor, driver cores, driver RAM... and these hyperparameters should have an effect on the speed of my calculation...

It seems like I should be able to adjust these parameters in a nested loop, e.g.

```
for (i in c(2L,4L)) for (j in c(2L,4L)) for (k in c('2g','4g')) {
  t0<-Sys.time()
  config$spark.driver.cores <- i
  config$spark.executor.cores <- j
  config$spark.executor.memory <- k
  sparkR.session(...,config=config)
  mysample<-sql('Select address1,address2,zip FROM MYDATA')
  doCalc<-dapply(mysample,...,schema=myOutputSchema)
  head(collect(doCalc),10)
  print(Sys.time()-t0)
  sparkR.stop()
}
```

This works outside of the loop with no issues. But inside of the loop, the cluster always fails to respond and always fails the initial stage:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                        (0 + 4) / 205]
18/06/13 18:39:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, hw09.mycluster.com, executor 1): 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
```

And it tries again, and again, and fails at multiple stages... How do we tune SparkR jobs? It seems like there's a critical failure in the R API for Spark that makes this impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a bug in Spark 2.0 and 2.1 in HDP 2.6 where the `daemon.R` file, which manages the messaging between Spark and the SparkR API, is not properly being deployed to the worker nodes.

Despite WARNING messages that `master=yarn-client` is deprecated, this is exactly the parameter that should be used to prevent the mismanagement of the API.